# IE 401 Unauthorized error accessing an API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I have two .net mvc projects one is the Main client application and other is API. All the methods are accessed through an api. Both the projects are hosted in IIS7.5 and when I run the application using windows authentication in chrome and firefox it works fine but throws 401 error in IE. There is no issue when I try to access the API URL directly in IE but through the application it gives 401 error. 
In IIS - 
Main Portal- windows (NTLM and Negotiate providers) and Impersonation enabled.
API - Windows (NTLM and Negotiate providers) and Impersonation enabled. 
If it's something with the permissions, it should fail in all browsers. Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: you're using NTLM as the primary method? Try switching to using Negotiate. Are both projects hosted on the same server? If not you may need Kerberos delegation. Not quite enough detail here to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If both your applications are hosted on the same server, push NTLM to the top in windows authentication providers section.

If they are not hosted on the same server, you will have to set up kerberos (Negotiate). Its not a very complex process. you need to understand your current environment and make appropriate configuration changes.